# Does ReviewManager's launchReviewFlow() display the dialog for users that already rated the app?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-play

Google's guide explains how to apply [Google Play In-App Reviews API](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review). 
It mentions that

> calling the launchReviewFlow method more than once during a short period of time (for example, less than a month) might not always display a dialog.

But I did not find in the guide nor in the [ReviewManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/review/ReviewManager) class documentation anything about what happens if a user has already rated the app.
I would not like to bother the users with asking to rate after they already did. Moreover, doing so might make them change a positive review to negative.
It makes sense that the API would not display the dialog to users that already rated the app. Moreover, I do not know of any way for the app to check if it was already rated. 
But I have not found anywhere where this is said.